# Data Deduplication and ReFS

Tags: filesystems, windows-server-2016

I have read a number of posts stating that only NTFS and CSVFS is supported with Data Deduplication, specifically not ReFS.

However in this article, which is quite new, it states that it is supported:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/refs/refs-overview

Can anyone concur that Data Deduplication does support ReFS?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a recent feature addition, available on Windows Server version 1709 and later. Anything before that will not support deduplication on ReFS.